# updating csv file in resources folder in maven java project

Tags: java, maven, resources

A csv file in /resources in my java maven application needs to be read as well as written.
Accessing the file using getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(/myFile.csv) in ResourceLoader class, i am able to write and read the file but the issue is the data is not appearing in the application after the restart of my system or after some time duration.

I tried using getResourceAsStream() by getting input stream ,but could write the file with it.
What might be the reason to it? Is there anything am doing wrong?

Comment: We need a [MCVE]

Comment: if you do that in an application packaged as a war or as a jar, you  are actually reading and writing a file that is extracted to the temp directory

Comment: How can I add those csv log files in java application where i need to package it as jar file.

Comment: In eclipse i have made res folder as source and its output folder is /target/classes (Default). How can i change it?